# Uniswap implement fails

Tags: solidity, blockchain, uniswap

I've been working on building a project using Aave3 Flashloan combined with UniswapV3 to arbitrage, but everytime the transactions are fail. I looked into the response of the error, it appears that something wrong with the Uniswap.

What might lead to the fail of swapping? I already check the pool have enough fund to perform the swap.Also,I had tested the swap part and flashloan part in testnet and they both works well separately. Moreover, if everything goes well, it fails only because of unable to payback the debt for the flashloan, I think the log should looks totally different.

Here's the transaction detail. https://etherscan.io/tx-decoder?tx=0x2eb057a8edd5eb6fbef562dc695908fc935c0864867472c663b64f936cfddd3f

Also, the following is the key part of my smart contract.

```
contract FlashLoanArbitrageFinalV4 is FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase {
    ISwapRouter public uniswapRouter;
    address payable owner;

constructor(address _aavePoolAddress, address _uniswapRouterAddress)
    FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(IPoolAddressesProvider(_aavePoolAddress))
{
    uniswapRouter = ISwapRouter(_uniswapRouterAddress);
    owner = payable(msg.sender);

}

function executeArbitrage (
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    bytes calldata params
) external onlyOwner {
    // Request a flash loan from Aave
    POOL.flashLoanSimple(address(this), asset, amount, params, 0);
}

function executeOperation(
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    uint256 premium,
    address initiator,
    bytes calldata params
) external override returns (bool){


    // Approve Uniswap to spend the asset
    IERC20(asset).approve(address(uniswapRouter), amount);
  


    // Set up the parameters for the swap
    ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams memory swapParams = ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams({
        path: params,
        recipient: address(this),
        deadline: block.timestamp+120,
        amountIn: amount,
        amountOutMinimum: 0 // You should calculate an appropriate minimum amount out
    });

    // Execute the swap on Uniswap V3
    uniswapRouter.exactInput(swapParams);

    // Repay the flash loan
    uint256 totalDebt = amount + premium;
    IERC20(asset).transfer(address(POOL), totalDebt);

    return true;
}
```

Any thoughts about the reason it fail?